# How to find outliers using avg and stddev?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having conflict filtering a Dataset<'Row> using the MEAN() and STDEV() built in functions in the org.apache.spark.sql.functions library.

This is the set of data I am working with (top 10):

```
Name    Size    Volumes
File1   1030    107529
File2   997     106006
File3   1546    112426
File4   2235    117335
File5   2061    115363
File6   1875    114015
File7   1237    110002
File8   1546    112289
File9   1030    107154
File10  1339    110276
```

What I am currently trying to do is find the outliers in this dataset. For that, I need to find the rows where the SIZE and VOLUMES are outliers using the 95% rule: μ - 2σ ≤ X ≤ μ + 2σ

This is the SQL-like query that I would like to run on this Dataset:

```
SELECT * FROM DATASET
WHERE size < (SELECT (AVG(size)-2STDEV(size)) FROM DATASET)
OR size > (SELECT (AVG(size)+2STDEV(size)) FROM DATASET)
OR  volumes < (SELECT (AVG(volumes)-2STDEV(volumes)) FROM DATASET)
OR volumes > (SELECT (AVG(volumes)+2STDEV(volumes)) FROM DATASET)
```

I don't know how to implement nested queries and I'm struggling to find a way to solve this. 
Also, if you happen to know other way of getting what I want, feel free to share it.

This is what I attempted to do but I get an error:

```
Column meanSize = functions.mean(size);
Column meanRecords = functions.mean(records);
Column stdSize = functions.stddev(size);
Column stdRecords = functions.stddev(records);

Column lowerSizeThreshold = size.lt((meanSize.minus(stdSize).minus(stdSize)));
Column upperSizeThreshold = size.gt(meanSize.plus(stdSize).plus(stdSize));
Column lowerRecordsThreshold = records.lt(meanRecords.minus(stdRecords).minus(stdRecords));
Column upperRecordsThreshold = records.gt(meanRecords.plus(stdRecords).plus(stdRecords));

Dataset<Row> outliers = dataFrame.where(lowerSizeThreshold.or(upperSizeThreshold).or(lowerRecordsThreshold).or(upperRecordsThreshold));
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: I kind of think this is because AVG and STDEV are aggregate functions, and in SQL I know you can't use an aggregate function on a where(filter). The only way around it is use those functions inside a nested query, but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: avg(cast(input[1, int, false] as bigint))

Comment: How about running all those nested queries as standalones, get the data and pass it to the original query ?

Comment: This is what I meant...
val result = session.load("(SELECT (AVG(size)-2STDEV(size)) FROM DATASET)T")
.....

val query = ss"(SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE size < ${result} ..... ) T";

val finalResult = session.load(query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments guys.

So this solution is for the Java implementation of Spark. If you want the implementation of Scala, look at Jacek Laskowski post.

Solution:

```
//first convert the columns Size and Records to a List<Double>
List<Double> sizeList = dataFrame.select("Size").javaRDD().map(f -> f.getDouble(0)).collect();
List<Double> recordsList = dataFrame.select("Records").javaRDD().map(f -> f.getDouble(0)).collect();

//then convert the lists into JavaDoubleRDD
JavaDoubleRDD size = sparkContext.parallelizeDoubles(sizeList);
JavaDoubleRDD records = sparkContext.parallelizeDoubles(recordsList);

//calculate the mean and stddev using the built in functions:
double sizeMean = size.mean();
double sizeStdev = size.stdev();
double recordsMean = records.mean();
double recordsStdev = records.stdev();
```

After that I can finally use those values in the Column comparison functions.
Hope you understood what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about Java that I'm currently not using at all, so here comes a Scala version that I hope might *somehow* help you to find a corresponding Java version.

---

What about the following solution?

```
// preparing the dataset
val input = spark.
  read.
  text("input.txt").
  as[String].
  filter(line => !line.startsWith("Name")).
  map(_.split("\\W+")).
  withColumn("name", $"value"(0)).
  withColumn("size", $"value"(1) cast "int").
  withColumn("volumes", $"value"(2) cast "int").
  select("name", "size", "volumes")
scala> input.show
+------+----+-------+
|  name|size|volumes|
+------+----+-------+
| File1|1030| 107529|
| File2| 997| 106006|
| File3|1546| 112426|
| File4|2235| 117335|
| File5|2061| 115363|
| File6|1875| 114015|
| File7|1237| 110002|
| File8|1546| 112289|
| File9|1030| 107154|
|File10|1339| 110276|
+------+----+-------+

// the final computation
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val (sizeAvg, sizeStddev, volumesAvg, volumesStddev) = input.
  groupBy().
  agg(avg("size"), stddev("size"), avg("volumes"), stddev("volumes")).
  as[(Double, Double, Double, Double)].
  head

val sizeLessThanStddev = col("size") < (sizeAvg - 2 * sizeStddev)
input.filter(sizeLessThanStddev)
```

This is only a first part of the 4-part `filter` operator, and am leaving the rest as a home exercise.